# How to set autocmd for files without a filetype?

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I want some `autocmd`s to run when I open a file without a filetype like `nvim` (no file name) or `nvim myfile` (no extension). I also want them to run when opening certain file types like `text` and `markdown` so I can't blacklist everything with a file type/extension. Is there a way to run certain `autocmd`s when no file type is known?

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate and compliant way is to extend filetypes with `after/ftplugin/{text,markdown}.vim`. Your "no extension" files can probably be detected as "text" filetype as well (or create a completely new filetype if you like). Then the actual functionality should be shared by a common autoloaded script.

But if you don't care then a single ftdetect script can do all work. Sort of,

> ~/.vim/ftdetect/stuff.vim

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *
    \    if !did_filetype() && empty(expand("<afile>:e")) || &ft is# "text" || &ft is# "markdown"
    \ |      " do some stuff...
    \ |  endif
```

Note: FileType for an empty unnamed buffer is not auto-detected. So if you really need to do something in this case you still have to catch `VimEnter` (or `BufNew`, or `BufEnter` etc.).

Comment: That's probably a "cleaner" way to do it than my answer :+1: (Thought I'd still use a list to check the filetype rather than `&ft is# "text" || &ft is# "markdown"`)

Comment: @statox If there could be more than two of them then I would do it also.

Comment: Can you provided a short script to automatically set `filetype` to `text` if typeless?

Comment: @JohnZhau Typeless vs noext vs both... You should probably decide what you need exactly and then you'll be able to change condition in the example above yourself.

Comment: @Matt, This works for existing files, such as README or TODO, but not if you open Vim with a new empty buffer or if you create a new empty buffer by using `:enew`. Could you improve the current version?

Comment: @johnc.j. A new buffer w/o name should not have any default filetype. Assign it manually if you need it.

Comment: Well, then maybe I need to open a separate question and to point that all I want is to disable auto-wrapping for files with `text` filetype, for files with `markdown` filetype, and for buffers with no filetype (such as a buffer that Vim creates for you by default on start).

Comment: @johnc.j. Disable globally. Enable for specific filetypes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of `&filetype` to determine if you are in a buffer without a filetype or with one of the filetype you want to target. One example could be like this:

```
function! DoStuff()
    if (exists('b:StuffDone') || index(['', 'text', 'markdown'], &ft) < 0)
        return
    endif
    let b:StuffDone = 1

    echo "Doing stuff for" &ft
endfunction

augroup Test
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * call DoStuff()
augroup END
```

Here your autocommand will call the function `DoStuff()` for all of your buffers, however the function itself will check the current filetype and stop its execution if the filetype is not empty and if it's not in the list of filetypes you want to handle.

As @Matt pointed out in the comments `BufEnter` is triggered each time you enter the buffer so that might be an issue. However reading [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events) I don't find an event which would trigger for all buffers after we have their filetype. To prevent running your code several time in the same buffer I set a variable `b:StuffDone` which is local to the buffer ([`:h b:`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#b%3A)) and test for its existence before running the code.

Comment: `BufEnter` is triggered _every time a buffer becomes active_. So it feels very wrong to use it for such task.

Comment: @Matt that's a good point, the issue is that the other event might not be triggered for unnamed buffers. So I updated the code with a guard to avoid running the code twice.

Comment: This should work, though personally I'd rather create `ftdetect/stuff.vim` with something like `if !did_filetype() || &ft is# 'text' || ...`.

Comment: I agree that using the built-in mechanism `ftdetect` has advantages. Maybe it would be worth it that you post a separate answer with this solution? It's always good to have diversity in the solutions offered to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want these autocmds to run on every file without a filetype and that there's some condition for when it should execute.

The built-in way to detect extensionless files is described in RECOGNIZING BY CONTENTS in `:help filetype-plugin`. It's down at the bottom:

> If your file cannot be recognized by its file name, you might be able to recognize it by its contents.  For example, many script files start with a line like:
>
> ```
>   #!/bin/xyz ~
> ```
>
> To recognize this script create a file "scripts.vim" in your runtime directory (same place where filetype.vim goes).  It might look like this:
>
> ```
>   if did_filetype()
>     finish
>   endif
>   if getline(1) =~ '^#!.*[/\\]xyz\>'
>     setf xyz
>   endif
> ```

You can even have multiple scripts.vim files in different runtimepath folders (so plugins can use scripts.vim).

Using `scripts.vim` would let you inspect the content to determine what filetype the file should have and then you can use the `FileType autocmd` to trigger.